# I/flutter ( 8131): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY - A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter

- I got this error. How can i solve it???

Appreciate any help

```
I/flutter ( 8131): The following assertion was thrown building Answer(dirty):

I/flutter ( 8131): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

I/flutter ( 8131): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':

I/flutter ( 8131): Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'

I/flutter ( 8131): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially

I/flutter ( 8131): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

I/flutter ( 8131): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
```

[image]

Comment: An answer is in error message: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Comment: `A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.` make sure you are passing a value  of type String.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Text` widget, you need to provide some value. 
Code like this will fail:

```
Text()
```

And code like this will pass:

```
Text('Some text')
```

Take a look inside your app where you forgot to put the value for `Text` widget.

If you are using variables, it might happen that value is null, and you didn't check for that.

```
Text(someValue == null ? '' : someValue)
```